# How to stop mesh parented to bone from going through other objects

Tags: bones

[image: object goes through other object]

I am a beginner, Whenever I move a leg of the robot, the object the bone is parented to goes through the mesh, is there any way to stop this?

Comment: I don't think so, you need to make sure that meshes don't go through each other by the bones keyframes

Comment: Not sure which parts of the geometry are clipping through each other from your description?
Also, is your Armature meant to be in a separate collection from your object?

Comment: @Toby I forgot to add the armature to the same collection, I just want the legs of the robot to not be able to go through the plane